# Trending tags query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a following database structure:

### Taggable table

```
| ID | Title          |
|----|----------------|
| 1  | Taggable title |
```

### Tagging (join table)

```
| id | taggable_id | taggable_type | tag_id | created_at          |
|----|-------------|---------------|--------|---------------------|
| 1  | 1           | Taggable      | 100    | 2018-01-01 09:00:00 |
```

### Tag

```
| id | name      |
|----|-----------|
|100 | First tag |
```

And i need to determine which one of those "tags" are trending recently. First challenge was to invent some simple algrithm of calculating what "trending" means. I decided to use a simplest one possible (that's not a big deal, it can be fine-tuned later) which is probably a bit crappy but works - count how many taggings each tag had for last hour and 3 hours ago, calculate difference between current count and old count and sort results by that difference.

My current SQL query for this looks like that:

```
select DISTINCT(tags.id), tags.*, (
    select COUNT(*)
    from taggings 
    where taggings.tag_id = tags.id
    and taggings.created_at::timestamp > now() - interval '3 hour'
) - (
    select COUNT(*) 
    from taggings 
    where taggings.tag_id = gutentag_tags.id
    and taggings.created_at <= now()::timestamp - interval '3 hour'
    and taggings.created_at > now()::timestamp - interval '12 hour'
) as hottness
from tags
left join taggings on tags.id = taggings.tag_id
where taggings.created_at >= now()::timestamp - interval '12 hours'
order by hottness desc
```

A ready to be used sqlfiddle is here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2298a/1

And i'm pretty sure it's completely bad and unoptimal and it would kill my server under higher load - but it works. Does anyone have an idea on how could i improve it or how can i change my attempt entirely to make it work better and safer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to check which tags are trending recently, why don't just take  a count of tags in time frame you want, sort them based on count and then choose top N based on your requirement.

Comment: i can't do that as such query would more or less return the same results all the time (that's a fault of source of the tags - there are some tags that are constantly super popular and will always be). I'm looking for a way to partially filter out these top popular ones and "give a chance" to the less popular ones as well. That's why i can't measure it simply by getting the most popular tags, i need to base it on their "average" score

Comment: What you can do is to query taggings table once for last 12 hours, and use case statement to calculate last 12 hours and last 3 hours results and subtract them. In that way you will be querying taggings table only once.

Answer (score 0):

It can be optimized by querying taggings only once

```
select tags.id, 
  count( case when taggings.created_at::timestamp > now() - interval '3 hour' then 1 else null end
  ) 
- 
   count ( case when
    taggings.created_at <= now()::timestamp - interval '3 hour'
    and taggings.created_at > now()::timestamp - interval '12 hour'
    then 1 else null end
) as hottness 
from tags
left join taggings on tags.id = taggings.tag_id
where taggings.created_at >= now()::timestamp - interval '12 hours'
group by tags.id
order by hottness desc
```